# How to download the iframe as pdf document in react?I have tried using jspdf and kendo-react-pdf but getting blank document

Tags: reactjs, kendo-ui, pdf-generation, jspdf

```
import { PDFExport, savePDF } from '@progress/kendo-react-pdf';

const [contentRef, setContentRef] = useState('');

const downloadCertificate = () => {
    const element: any =
        document.querySelector('#certificate') || document.body;
    savePDF(element, { paperSize: 'A4' });
};

const onClickDownload = () => {
    downloadCertificate();
};

return (
    <div>
        <PDFExport ref={pdfExportComponent} paperSize="A4">
            <iframe
                id="certificate"
                title="View your certificate"
                className="u-els-margin-left-3x u-els-margin-right-3x"
                width="776px"
                height="600px"
                srcDoc={contentRef}
            />
        </PDFExport>
    </div>
);
```

> Using the above set of code to generate the pdf, I am importing the PDF Export and wrapping it around the block of code i want to export as pdf. Here the `srcDoc` of  iframe is what I exactly want to export which assigned to a `useState`. So after the page renders the info is stored in `srcDoc` and I want to export this as pdf on click of the button which is part of the return.

Answer (score 0):

currently `iframe`s are not supported as part of the PDF export: https://www.telerik.com/kendo-react-ui/components/drawing/limitations-browser-support/#toc-elements-and-styles